# Getting error: "Missing ')' in function parameter list." while passing variable in param with hyphen in name in powershell script

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have a Powershell script to which I am passing a parameters. The name of one variable has a hyphens in it (variable name format: testName-2-1-dev). But I am getting the error below while executing it:

`Missing ')' in function parameter list.`

Script:

```
param($testName-2-1-dev)

$'testName-2-1-dev'   #.....2

$updatePermissions = az keyvault set-policy -n $keyvault  --secret-permissions get list --object-id $testName`-2`-1`-dev
$updatePermissions
```

I tried to add quotes same as that in 2 and also tried to add ` character before the hyphen, but it did not work out. Can I please get help in this?

Comment: Parameter names should never have hyphens as they break parsing. Don't use hyphens

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: Unfortunately, I cannot change the name.

Comment: Whats the reason you couldn't ? Parameters are bound by name or by position or by pipeline but their name doesn't actually matter in most cases, __what's important is their value__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use curly brackets (`${...}`) to qualify the parameter/variable name:

```
param(${testName-2-1-dev})

az keyvault set-policy -n $keyvault --secret-permissions get list --object-id ${testName-2-1-dev}
```

Now you can invoke it with:

```
.\script.ps1 -testName-2-1-dev 123
```